# vba copyfromrecordset only outputting first column

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, odbc

I am using the MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver to connect my Excel VBA app to a MySQL database, which works great. I open a connection and then use the following sub to query the database and output the result to a range in the worksheet.

```
Public Sub output_result(query As String, output As Range, Optional connection As connection)

    If connection Is Nothing Then
    Set connection = OpenConnection()
    End If

    Dim Result As ADODB.Recordset
    ' Load all the records from the database
    Set Result = connection.execute(query)

    ' Insert them into the dedicated area
    Call output.CopyFromRecordset(Result)

End Sub
```

I have a project that uses this sub several times with different queries and it works but there is one query where only the first column of results is output.

It is a long query with a few joins in it but if I copy/paste the query directly into phpmyadmin it runs fine and the whole result is displayed.

Any ideas why I'm only getting the first column? The query in question gets about 15 rows of 26 fields.

Comment: In my opinion the problem lies outside the code you presented. If it works fine with other queries than obviously you need to search outside. Are data in your table consistent? Don't you made any mistake in query string (SQL)? etc...

Comment: As I mentioned, the query itself is fine. I paste it into phpmyadmin and it works. I was resorting to writing the recordset to a vba array (using `.GetRows`) and outputting the array to a range but that is a hacky way of doing it and extra conditions must be accounted for for when the result is empty

Comment: I solved this. The issue was because the `output` range I specified was 1 cell. When I made the range the same size as the result it gets output correctly. Interestingly only occurred on this one query and not others. Maybe some strange goings on on this specific worksheet.